# How to check if sub-folder text file exists

Tags: vb.net, text-files

I am trying to search if a text file in a sub-folder exists.

This is the code I am using:

```vb
'Checks the program's root folder to see if the root folder exists.
Dim FolderName = New DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Cake Orders\" & TextBox1.Text))
Dim McKnwoll As String = Path.Combine(FolderName.FullName, Trim(TextBox2.Text) & (" ") & Trim(TextBox3.Text) + ".RTO")
If Not McKnwoll.Exists Then
    ‘Message to user that file does not exist in sub-folder
Else
     ‘Message to user that file does exists in sub-folder
End If
```

I am getting an error that 'Exists' is not a member of 'String'. How can I re-work my code to check if the text file whose name is in the format of "TextBox2.Text & (" ") & TextBox3.Text + ".RTO"; exists.

I am using Visual Basic 2010 Express. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but did you even *try* to google? `.net file exists` returns a link to the `File.Exists` method as the first result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`File.Exists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a Boolean indicating whether a file at a certain path exists:

```
If File.Exists(pathToFile) Then
    ...
End If
```

Be sure to include `Imports System.IO` at the top of your source code file.

Comment: You should probably mention that it returns False if the file does exist but the user/application doesn't have permission to access it. You know people don't actually _read_ MSDN. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You seem quite new in programming. Welcome.

That error message you got ('Exists' is not a member of 'String') tells you exactely what is wrong: You try to ask a string (some text) whether it exists, but what you like to do is to ask a file whether it exists.

The class that provides information about a file is called "FileInfo", and FileInfo has an "Exists" property that you can call:

```
Dim myFileInfo As New FileInfo(McKnwoll)
If myFileInfo.Exists Then
  'do something
End If
```

That's the object oriented answer, Heinzi's more service oriented one but works, of course, too.

There have been several other small issues I noticed with your code, e.g.

```
"Cake Orders\" & TextBox1.Text
```

does not use Path.Combine but makes a string concatenation using fix a "\" as directory separater. Or that the DirectoryInfo is not really used here, the string to the folder is enough.

You also try to handle 3 different issues (reading the values from the user interface, constructing the fullname of the file, checking whether the file exists) in one single code block. I would split them into 3 different ones (actually 4, I would add another one for displaying error messages).

Your simple few lines of codes could be complicated like this ;-)

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ReadFileIfPossible(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReadFileIfPossible(subfolder As String, part1 As String, part2 As String)
        'Get the path to the RTO file
        Dim myFilePath As String = Nothing
        Try
            myFilePath = GetRtoFilePath(subfolder, part1, part2)
        Catch ex As Exception
            DisplayErrorMessage("Error constructing file name! Please check the values of TextBox1, TextBox2 and TextBox3.")
            Return
        End Try
        'Get the file info
        Dim myFile As FileInfo = Nothing
        Try
            myFile = New FileInfo(myFilePath)
        Catch ex As Exception
            DisplayErrorMessage(ex.Message)
            Return
        End Try
        'Check whether it exists
        Dim myExists As Boolean = False
        Try
            myExists = myFile.Exists 'it's IO, everything might throw an exception...
        Catch ex As Exception
            DisplayErrorMessage(ex.Message)
            Return
        End Try
        'Display message if not found
        If (Not myExists) Then
            DisplayErrorMessage("File ""{0}"" could not be found!", myFilePath)
            Return
        End If
        'Read the file
        Dim myLines As String() = Nothing
        Try
            myLines = File.ReadAllLines(myFile.FullName, New UTF8Encoding(True))
        Catch ex As Exception
            DisplayErrorMessage(ex.Message)
            Return
        End Try
        'Do something with it...
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function GetRtoFilePath(subfolder As String, part1 As String, part2 As String) As String
        'Check args
        If (subfolder Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("subfolder")
        If (part1 Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("part1")
        If (part2 Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("part2")
        'Normalize args
        part1 = part1.Trim()
        part2 = part2.Trim()
        'Build path
        Dim myDesktopPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
        Dim myFolderPath As String = Path.Combine(myDesktopPath, "Cake Orders")
        myFolderPath = Path.Combine(myFolderPath, subfolder)
        Dim myFileName As String = String.Format("{0} {1}.RTO", part1, part2)
        Dim myResult As String = Path.Combine(myFolderPath, myFileName)
        myResult = Path.GetFullPath(myResult)
        'Return result
        Return myResult
    End Function

    Private Sub DisplayErrorMessage(message As String, ParamArray args As Object())
        Dim myMsg As String = String.Format(message, CType(args, Object()))
        MsgBox(myMsg, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Have fun.